# Detect .Net 4.7 with Wix Installer 3.11

Tags: .net, wix, installation

any ideas on how to handle .Net 4.7 in Wix?
The documentation only shows support for 462, unless I'm missing something.
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html
I found this: http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/ But I have never use it.
Any advice is appreciated!

Tnx!

Comment: you can duplicate the implementation for checks of .net that are used in the NetFxExtension by looking at its code here https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib

Comment: You can check the registry using RegistrySearch and the following page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The following fragment (modified from 4.6.2) should work when you add `<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx47Redist"/>` in your bundle's Chain. This requires the offline installer (downloaded from the NetFx47RedistLink) to be present in the relative source path ..\Redist\NETFX47 folder for bundle compilation. You also need to add the NetFxExtension in your bundle's references and add `xmlns:netfx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension' in the bundle wxs.

```
<Fragment>
    <?define NetFx47MinRelease = 460798 ?>
    <?define NetFx47WebLink = http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/E/A/AEAE0F3F-96E9-4711-AADA-5E35EF902306/NDP47-KB3186500-Web.exe ?>
    <?define NetFx47RedistLink = http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/D/3/DD35CC25-6E9C-484B-A746-C5BE0C923290/NDP47-KB3186497-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe ?>
    <?define NetFx47EulaLink = http://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html ?>

    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="NetFx47Redist" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="$(var.NetFx47EulaLink)" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="NetFx47RedistDetectCondition" Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx47MinRelease)" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="NetFx47RedistInstallCondition" Value="" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="NetFx47RedistPackageDirectory" Value="Redist\NETFX47\" Overridable="yes" />

    <PackageGroup Id="NetFx47Redist">
        <ExePackage
            DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7"
            InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx47FullLog].html&quot;"
            RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx47FullLog].html&quot;"
            UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx47FullLog].html&quot;"
            PerMachine="yes"
            DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx47RedistDetectCondition)"
            InstallCondition="!(wix.NetFx47RedistInstallCondition)"
            Id="NetFx47Redist"
            Vital="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            Protocol="netfx4"
            DownloadUrl="$(var.NetFx47RedistLink)"
            LogPathVariable="NetFx47FullLog"
            Compressed="no"
            SourceFile="..\Redist\NETFX47\NDP47-KB3186497-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
            Name="!(wix.NetFx47RedistPackageDirectory)NDP47-KB3186497-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
        >
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

You also need to add the following RegistrySearch which uses the Util extension, add it to the references and `xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'` in the bundle.

```
        <util:RegistrySearch
            Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"
            Variable="NETFRAMEWORK45"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
            Value="Release"
            Result="value"
        />
```